# unknown behavior in php login system

Tags: php, oop, pdo, php-5.5

I have this method to verify username and password but i faced weird behavior i don't know why like this in user.php :

```
public static function verify_user($username,$password)
{
    global $database;
    

    $sql = "select * from users where username= :username and password= :password";
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    

    $database->bind(':username', $username);
    $database->bind(':password', $password);
    $row=$database->single();   
        
    //* Create Array to put the objects inside it
    $the_object_array=array();

    //*Create an instance of the class and put inside the_object_array[]
    $the_object_array[]=self::instant_class($row);

    pretty_print(false);

    
    return !empty($the_object_array) ? array_shift($the_object_array) : false;

    

}


private  static function  instant_class($the_record)
{
     //* here we instantiate the User class it self using
    //* self keyword
     $the_object=new self;

    // $the_object->id=$found_user['id'];
   
     foreach ($the_record as $the_attribute => $value) {
        
        if($the_object->has_the_attribute($the_attribute)){
            $the_object->$the_attribute=$value;
        }
     }
     /* reset pointer, start again on step one*/
     reset($the_record);
     return $the_object;

}
```

And i have this in login.php :

```
<?php


// if ($session->is_signed_in()) {
//  redirect("index.php");
// }


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    
    $username=trim($_POST['username']);
    $password=trim($_POST['password']);

    //*Method to check DB user
    $userfound=User::verify_user($username,$password);
    //pretty_print($userfound);


    if ($userfound) {
        
        $session->login($userfound);
        //redirect("index.php");
        //pretty_print($userfound);
        

    }else{
        $the_msg="Your username or password are incorrect";
        // pretty_print($userfound);

    }
}
else{

    //$the_msg="";

    $username="";
    $password="";
}


 ?>

 
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">

<h4 class="bg-danger"><?php echo $the_msg; ?></h4>
    
<form id="login-id" action="" method="post">
```

**Edited to be more clear:**

- database.php :

```
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
                case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
                case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
                default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }

        try {
            $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception -> ';
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
        
    }

public function single(){
        try {
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception -> ';
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

**The main error is :**
I can't fetch this message `$the_msg="Your username or password are incorrect";` when user entered wrong username or wrong password .

and the errors in this screenshot is :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\admin\includes\user.php on line 104
>
> Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\admin\includes\user.php on line 111

So the result is like this screenshot ,i don't know why ??

[image]

Comment: `query` executes the query and doesn't use placeholders. What is `bind` and `single`? Those error messages are almost impossible to read, copy and paste them here. Gray on black is almost useless.

Comment: I have edited the original question to be more clear ,Thanks.

Comment: first error says, that you have no match in db for given username and passoword (invalid argument supplied). So you should check first if you got at least one row returned.

Comment: the 2 warnings are easy to solved , but the problem is in the main error that I can't fetch the message for wrong username or password

Comment: you'd need to declare a default value (empty string) for `$the_msg`

Comment: and `$the_object_array` will _never_ be empty, because you add _one_ item to it - even if that item is false/null.

Comment: nice ,so what is your check condition suggestion other than empty method to check this ?

Answer (score 0):

Two things could be happening with your `foreach` loop.  Either no records are returned from your PDO statement or your PDO `excute()` or `fetch()` executions errors out and `single()` returns your try / catch error message.

Given that you then get a `reset() expects parameter 1 to be array` error message, it's definitely the first (your PDO statement isn't returning anything).  `fetch()` returns `false` when nothing is found.